# JQuery select div text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

This is my html code. I've to select `active` (not the link) when a link is clicked and convert `active` into `<a>` tag.

```
<div class="archiveDelete">
<div class="">
active&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:void(0)"> archived</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"> deleted</a>
</div>
```

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Ufx/1/).

How to select the text 'active' but not the links? I've tried with `$('.archiveDelete').text()` but it contains `active|archived|deleted`.

What I'm trying is, I've to convert a clicked link into text and other text into link.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put "active" into its own `<span>`? This will also allow you to put a margin on those spans, so you won't need the `&nbsp;`s. Personal preference, but I find these annoying.

Comment: On which link is clicked ?

Comment: `innerHTML()` is not working

Comment: are you trying that on click of other links active should become a link and vice versa ?

Comment: I'm trying to convert a link to text when it is clicked and convert other text to a link. For ex, when archived is clicked it should become a text and active should become a link

Comment: Please? Can you explain again? No, really all over again.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z22dB/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny you are close http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Z22dB/1/ this is my updated fiddle. it works one time only

Comment: after the first time what do you want to do

Comment: @ArunPJohny After that, when I clicked again the active it should be converted into text and archived should become a link

Comment: you can change the html right

Comment: Why? is it not possible without change the html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check following fiddle for your answers :

http://jsfiddle.net/JLQ5r/7/

Changed HTML :

```
<div class="archiveDelete">
<!-- The links at the bottom right side of the table-->
<div class="">
    <span class="spanclass">active</span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="links"><span class="spanclass">archived</span></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="links"><span class="spanclass">deleted</span></a>
</div>
 </div>
```

Changed Jquery :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.archiveDelete a', function() {
        var thistext = $(this).text();
        //$(this).replaceWith("<span class='spanclass'>"+$(this).text()+"</span>");
        $(this).contents().unwrap();
        alert(thistext);
        $( ".spanclass" ).each(function() {
            var spantext = $(this).text();
            //alert(spantext);
            //alert($(this).parent('a').length);
            if(thistext!=spantext && $(this).parent('a').length == 0) {
                $(this).wrap( "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='links'></a>" );
            }
        });

    });
});
```

on click of an anchor it will be changed to simple text and rest will become anchors.

Please check and revert for any queries.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert anchor tag to text you can do some thing like this

check fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Ufx/18/

```
$('.archiveDelete a').click(function(){
    //alert($(this).text());
    var all=$(this).contents().unwrap();
     alert(all);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to do this, for converting the `active` to an anchor you can use `html()` and `replace()` methods:

```
$(this.parentNode).html(function(_, oldHTML){
    return oldHTML.replace(/(active)/, "<a href='#'>active</a>");
});
```

Converting the anchor to textNode:

```
$(this.parentNode).find('a:contains(active)') // or .find('a')
                  .replaceWith(function() { 
                       return this.textContent || this.innerText;
                  });
```

You could also use another element instead of using textNode, then you could replace the element with another element using `replaceWith` method. The other option is adding/removing classes, then in your click handler you can check that element has a certain className, if yes *do this* otherwise *do nothing*.

Update:

If you want to convert the clicked element to a textNode:

```
$(this).replaceWith(function() { 
    return this.textContent || this.innerText;
});
```

Note that since you are generating `a` element dynamically you should also delegate the events:

```
$('.archiveDelete').on('click', 'a', function(){
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Yes, it converts active to a link but not the current link to text

Comment: @ling.s If you want to convert the existing links to textNodes, use the second snippet and remove the `:contains(a)` selector, it will replace all the anchors with their textContents.

Comment: This is fine, but it will replace all links to text, I want to replace only the clicked link

Answer (score 0):

Try below script -

```
var $element = $('.archiveDelete');
$element.clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `$(this).text()` and it will show the link on which you clicked.

Edited Code:

```
  $('.archiveDelete a').click(function(){
    //alert($(this).text());
    var all=$(this).text();
    alert(all);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Ufx/9/

To get href of the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Ufx/17/

```
  $('.archiveDelete a').click(function(){
    var all=$(this).attr('href'); //to get HREF
    alert(all);
  });
```

To display `active` see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Ufx/19/

Comment: I van easily get the clicked link, but i need to get the text on the div not the link

Comment: what do u mean by text? `href`

Comment: Nope, read my question carefully. I don't need the href I've to change the text `active` into href

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.archiveDelete a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Ufx/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, i've shifted the class (acrhieveDelete) to the next div.

```
  <div class="">
    <div class="archiveDelete">
    active | 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">archived</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)">deleted</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  $('.archiveDelete a').click(function(){
    var all=$('.archiveDelete').contents();
     var str = all.first().text().replace('|','');
      all.first().replaceWith( "<a href='javascript:void(0)'>"+str+"</a> | " );

  });
```